# SQL statement causing timeouts

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code that I really need to get revised.  I did it in a simple way as I am not a pro in SQL.

```
SELECT   Inv1.AutoIndex, Inv1.DocState, Inv1.OrderNum,      
Inv1.ExtOrderNum, dbo.Client.ubARSMS, dbo.Client.Fax1
FROM       dbo.InvNum Inv1 INNER JOIN
           dbo.Client ON Inv1.AccountID = dbo.Client.DCLink
WHERE     (dbo.Client.ubARSMS = 1) 
  AND (Inv1.OrderDate >= dbo.Client.udARSMSACTDATE)
  AND Inv1.OrderNum NOT IN (SELECT o.OrderNum
                            FROM dbo.net_OrderSMSLog o
                            WHERE (o.DocState = 4))
  AND Inv1.AutoIndex NOT IN(SELECT Inv2.OrigDocID 
                            FROM dbo.InvNum Inv2
                            WHERE Inv2.OrderNum = Inv1.OrderNum)
   AND 
        (
        DATEPART(YEAR, Inv1.InvDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
        AND DATEPART(MONTH, Inv1.InvDate) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
        AND DATEPART(DAY, Inv1.InvDate) = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())

    OR      
        DATEPART(YEAR, Inv1.InvDate) = DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()))
        AND DATEPART(MONTH, Inv1.InvDate) = DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()))
        AND DATEPART(DAY, Inv1.InvDate) = DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()))
    )
```

I need this to work as fast as possible.

Comment: Table definitions, incl constraints and indexes.

Comment: Is your `OR` logic really correct?

Comment: Or logic is correct, this code pulls the records correctly, it only times out often

Comment: Thanks for the down vote @a_horse_with_no_name. I'm struggling under pressure here, and instead of helping, you down voting??

Comment: my apologies @GordonLinoff.  The OR part was incorrect. I've edited the question to reflect the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my query above was working when the load on the server was minimal and there were less records to pull.

The timeout was the only thing that I needed to be handled without having to create indexes on the clients Main database.

So I simply created a 2nd windows service that checks if the 1st windows service crashes/stopped due to timeout, then restart it.

Solved my issue of the timeout crashing my service.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT Inv1.AutoIndex, Inv1.DocState, Inv1.OrderNum,      
       Inv1.ExtOrderNum, c.ubARSMS, c.Fax1
FROM dbo.InvNum Inv1 INNER JOIN
     dbo.Client c
     ON Inv1.AccountID = c.DCLink AND Inv1.OrderDate >= c.udARSMSACTDATE
WHERE (c.ubARSMS = 1) AND
      Inv1.OrderNum NOT IN (SELECT o.OrderNum
                            FROM dbo.net_OrderSMSLog o
                            WHERE (o.DocState = 4)
                           ) AND
      Inv1.AutoIndex NOT IN (SELECT Inv2.OrigDocID 
                             FROM dbo.InvNum Inv2
                             WHERE Inv2.OrderNum = Inv1.OrderNum
                            ) OR  
      (Inv1.InvDate >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1 GETDATE()) as date) AND
       Inv1.InvDate < CAST(GETDATE() as date) 
      )
```

This is really two queries, which you can combine using `UNION ALL`.  The first is:

```
SELECT Inv1.AutoIndex, Inv1.DocState, Inv1.OrderNum,      
       Inv1.ExtOrderNum, c.ubARSMS, c.Fax1
FROM dbo.InvNum Inv1 INNER JOIN
     dbo.Client c
     ON Inv1.AccountID = c.DCLink AND Inv1.OrderDate >= c.udARSMSACTDATE
WHERE (c.ubARSMS = 1) AND
      Inv1.OrderNum NOT IN (SELECT o.OrderNum
                            FROM dbo.net_OrderSMSLog o
                            WHERE (o.DocState = 4)
                           ) AND
      Inv1.AutoIndex NOT IN (SELECT Inv2.OrigDocID 
                             FROM dbo.InvNum Inv2
                             WHERE Inv2.OrderNum = Inv1.OrderNum
                            )
```

For this, I would suggest indexes on `Client(ubARSMS, DCLink, udARSMACTDate)`, `InvNum(ClientId, OrderNum, AutoIndex)`, `InvNum(OrderNum, OrigDocId)`, and `net_OrderSMSLog(DocState, OrderNum)`.

For the second query:

```
SELECT Inv1.AutoIndex, Inv1.DocState, Inv1.OrderNum,      
       Inv1.ExtOrderNum, c.ubARSMS, c.Fax1
FROM dbo.InvNum Inv1 INNER JOIN
     dbo.Client c
     ON Inv1.AccountID = c.DCLink AND Inv1.OrderDate >= c.udARSMSACTDATE
WHERE (Inv1.InvDate >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1 GETDATE()) as date) AND
       Inv1.InvDate < CAST(GETDATE() as date) 
      )
```

You want an index on `InvNum(InvDate, AccountId, OrderDate)` and `Client(DCLink, udARSMACTDate)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. How can I do this without creating indexes on the database? This is the clients Pastel DB and I don't want to do anything that will affect other queries on the system. I need this query running fast locally within itself.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking to be spoon fed here. I'm not a pro SQL guy and I really need this query. please can you provide me with a query full solution with the UNION ALL. Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CypherNet Indexes are how databases work fast. Without them, you should expect timeouts occasionally. If you want to allow the queries to be slow, increase the timeout length